# How to dynamically refine the name/description of a payment link in Stripe?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, stripe-payments

I'm creating a marketplace prototype using ASP.NET Core, React and Stripe.

> Scenario.
>
> A customer can purchase a number of products through the marketplace.
>
> However, for customer's convenience, it's useful for him let to
> specify which area the product will belong to.
>
> E.g. the customer wants to buy three bananas, and would like to
> specify that one is for the Alice, another for Bob, and the third for
> Charlie.

Now, the Stripe's price entry is supposed to be ONE, as well as the product entry.

So, my problem is how to feed the checkout form so that an extra field will appear (the red one in the picture below). That to clarify the customer the exact reason of the purchase.

Of course, this is meant for the payment-link instance: for every price-quantity pair the customer puts in the basket, the related text could be specified.

Everything said should go along throughout the workflow, up to the invoice it will be mailed him/her.

So far, the C# backend code is not much different from the Stripe's suggested one:

```
[HttpPost("create-checkout-session")]
public async Task<ActionResult<object>> CreateCheckoutSessionAsync([FromServices] IMemoryCache cache)
{
    // ...

    var options = new SessionCreateOptions
        {
            UiMode = "embedded",
            LineItems = [],
            Mode = "payment",
            ReturnUrl = cart_content.ReturnUrl,
        };

    foreach (var item in cart_content.Products)
    {
        options.LineItems.Add(new()
                              {
                                  Price = item.PriceId,
                                  Quantity = item.Quantity,
                              });
    }

    var service = new SessionService();
    Session session = await service.CreateAsync(options);

    var result = new
        {
            clientSecret = session.ClientSecret,
        };

    return new ActionResult<object>(result);
}
```

However, it seems that the `SessionLineItemOptions` class doesn't offer any extra field facility.

Is there any other way to achieve all that?

[image]

Comment: there isn't really any great way to go about this in Checkout Sessions. You would probably be better off building your own UI instead with the Payment Element

Comment: @alex I'm afraid you're right.